# spring mvc without web server (tomcat or glassfish)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I just need a little hint in what direction my research should go.
Because currently I have a spring standalone jar project (spring-context, spring-data-jpa and hibernate entitymanager. Everything set up without xml files).
Now I want to run this application on two computers inside a network. Both should be able to [send objects over the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615882/sending-receiving-objects-over-network-in-java). But I want to accomplish this without a web server (so no tomcat or glassfish).
Is this even possible? and how is this called?
I have problems finding something close to this plan. Most of the time I find tutorials and threads for sending objects with tomcat. But I more or less only need a open port that listens to incomming objects.

**EDIT**
Later I also want to put a third player in the communication process: A website. So then two standalone jar programs and one website will pass objects around. That's why I hope spring mvc will work for a stanalone solution as well.

(I know that this question will get tagged down, but it's ok, as long as I get some designations I can use to research better, so thanks ...)

Comment: MVC without a server isn't going to happen... If you only want to send object, use JMS or another technology to pass things around, that way you can run without mvc.

Answer (score 3):

You have many specifications. ProtoBuf seems to be interesting https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/java

Without having server it would be a pain for you as you will have to implement concurrency, security and this kind of stuff.

Does Spring Boot work for you? Server is embeded ;-)

Comment: First thank you very much for your answer. And when I understood you correctly, spring boot will bring a server within the classspath in order to listen to spring request mappings? without installing a tomcat manually? If so, this seems to be the perfect solution especially when I later want to add a website to the communication process.

Answer (score 1):

What about use normal java sockets? There is plenty information if you google it. If you need help with this just let me know and I can send you some java application. Just type Java Sockets and lets learn!

Alvaro.

Comment: thank you very much for your fast answer. later I also want to put a website in the communication process, so that two standalone spring jar files and one website will be able to pass objects around. Is a java socket still working then? If so, will give it a try...